# Extra parenthesis and apostrophes when using multiple arguments print-function in python

Tags: python, printing, arguments, python-2.x

In python I was trying to use the print-function with the following input.

```
room = 503
print ('I am staying in room number', room)
```

I would expect the following output:

```
I am staying in room number 503
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
('I am staying in room number', 503)
```

How can I make it so that it just as smooth as my expectations?

It seems to work fine when I only have one argument in the print-function..

Comment: Which variant of Python?  Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, there are no parenthesis for the `print` construct. So, to match your expectation, you need to write:

```
room = 503
print 'I am staying in room number', room
```

Note that when you write:

```
room = 503
print ('I am staying in room number', room)
```

...you are actually printing a tuple of values (because of the comma), and tuples are printed with surrounding parenthesis.

And in this example:

```
print ('Hello')
```

...it will not print parenthesis because there is no comma and as such it is not a tuple. To get a tuple of a single value and print corresponding parenthesis, you can add a leading comma:

```
print ('Hello',)
```

Note that in Python 3.x, `print()` is a function and always takes parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this works:

```
room = 503
print'I am staying in room number',room
print('I am staying in room number'),(room)
print('I am staying in room number 503')
print room
```

Output:

```
I am staying in room number 503
I am staying in room number 503
I am staying in room number 503
503
```

This seems weird, am I right?